# How do you turn on a phone's lamp in Flutter on Android using "lamp 0.0.6"?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have tried to follow the steps mentionned on the package's page but it simply does not work. The Lamp.flash() and Lamp.turnOn() functions do nothing. I have tried this example: https://pub.dev/packages/lamp#-readme-tab- and the application does not turn on the flash.

Comment: are you getting any error in log? did you try flutter clean and then run flutter run command ?

Comment: why don’t you ask directly author of that library on it’s github repos?